# example Wordpress AJAX call indicates success, but doesn't pass the data it should

Tags: ajax, wordpress

This is a dumb question, but here goes -

I'm trying to wrap my head around Wordpress's AJAX calls. In my PHP module, I have

```
function example_ajax_request() {
  $fruit = $_POST['fruit'];
  echo $fruit;
  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

In my JS file, I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('ajaxurl', ajaxurl);
    // This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
    var fruit = 'Banana';
    console.log('call fruit', fruit);
    // This does the ajax request (The Call).
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
        data: {
            'action': 'example_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below
            'fruit': 'apple' // This is the variable we are sending via AJAX
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
            window.alert('data', data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            window.alert('error', errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

The thing I don't understand is that when I load the page, I get a popup with 'data' - which indicates the success function, but no actual data (the `echo 'someResult';` part). Also, I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: I guess because alert accept only one parameter. Change it to alert('data ' + data) or use console.log

Comment: I tried both of those, and it seems like the data variable is still empty

Comment: add type: 'POST' to ajax-call params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aliakseyenka Ihar gave me an idea, and my final code is:

```
<?php function example_ajax_request() {
  $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
echo '{fruit:\''.$fruit.'\'}';
die();
}

// This bit is a special action hook that works with the WordPress AJAX functionality.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

and also

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log('ajaxurl', ajaxurl);
    // This is the variable we are passing via AJAX
    var fruit = 'Banana';
    console.log('call fruit', fruit);
    // This does the ajax request (The Call).
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined and points to admin-ajax.php
        data: {
            'action': 'example_ajax_request', // This is our PHP function below
            'fruit': 'apple' // This is the variable we are sending via AJAX
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request (The Callback)
            console.log('the data is: ', data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            window.alert('error ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem ended up being with the `$_POST`, rather than the `ECHO`.